# get Count of distinct value for multiple column from Dataframe using Spark and Java8

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8

I want to get Count of distinct value for multiple column from Dataframe using Spark and Java8

Input DataFrame  - Need to write code for Dynamic columns - Columns may be added later

```
+----+----+----+
|Col1|Col2|Col3|
+----+----+----+
|A1|Y|B2|Y|C3|Y|
|A1|Y|B2|N|C3|Y|
|A1|Y|B2|Y|C3|N|
+----+----+----+
```

Output DateFrame

```
+--------+---------------------+--------------------+
|Col1    | Col2                | Col3               |
+--------+---------------------+--------------------+
|A1|Y - 3| B2|Y - 2 & B2|N - 1 | C3|Y - 3 & C3|N -1 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+------+
```

Comment: Look into `groupingBy` and with downstream as  `counting` Collectors approach.

Comment: Dataset<Row> df_dup = spark.read().format("json").load("src/main/resources/new2.json");

  df_dup = df_dup.groupBy("Col2").agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.count("Col2").as("Count"));

  df_dup = df_dup.withColumn("Final", org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat(df_dup.col("Col2"),
    org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit(" - "), df_dup.col("Count")));
  df_dup = df_dup.drop(df_dup.col("Col2"));
  df_dup = df_dup.drop(df_dup.col("Count"));

  df_dup.show();   Unable to get the expected output in effective way  - Appriciated if you would help to write a code in java8.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you a bit, in scala using rdd but in java should be very similar.

```
  val df = Seq(("a", "a", "a"), ("a", "b", "c"), ("b", "b", "c")).toDF("Col1","Col2","Col3")
  df.show()

  val ok = df.rdd.map(s => {
    var arr = new Array[(String, String)](s.size)
    for (i <- 0 to s.size - 1) {
      arr(i) = (s.getString(i), s.schema.fieldNames(i))
    }
    arr
  }).map(s => {
    for (i <- s) yield ((i._2, i._1), 1)
  }).flatMap(s => s)
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    .map(s => (s._1._1, s._1._2 + "=" + s._2))
    .reduceByKey(_ +","+ _)

  ok.foreach(println(_))
```

```
 +----+----+----+
 |Col1|Col2|Col3|
 +----+----+----+
 |   a|   a|   a|
 |   a|   b|   c|
 |   b|   b|   c|
 +----+----+----+

 (Col1,a=2,b=1)
 (Col2,b=2,a=1)
 (Col3,a=1,c=2)
```